# Number to unique character combination

Tags: php, character, combinations

I want to create a character combination for every number from 1-infinity in PHP.

Characters allowed are a-z

- 0 -> a
- 1 -> b
- 2 -> c
- ...
- 25 -> z
- 26 -> aa
- 27 -> ab

I hope you get what I mean.  Thank you!

Comment: why not use a UUID generator?

Comment: Every number? What about simply every positive integer within the range that of MAX_PHP_INT?

Comment: It’s rather a [base conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Base_conversion).

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: `$i = 0; $j = 'a'; while (true) { echo $i++, '->', $j++, PHP_EOL; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added all the comments inline.

```
//Your number
$num = 700;

//Stores the result
$result = "";

$count = 0;
while ($num>=1)
{
    /*If we don't do the following line,
    26 will be "ba" but not "aa"
    As a number 2 can be written as 02 in decimal, but in your example we can't do that, as you won't allow writing 02 as "ac", but simply "c".*/
    if ($num < 26) $offset=9; else $offset=10;

    //The following part is just a simple base conversion
    $remainder = $num%26;
    $digit =  base_convert($remainder+$offset,10,36);
    $result .= $digit;
    $num = floor($num/26);

    $count++;
}

//Display in reverse order
$result = strrev($result);
echo $result;
```